# Faraday's law of induction: why there is no constant of proportionality?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction, history

I am learning the Maxwell's equations on my own, and I ran into some questions about Faraday's law $$\nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf B.$$

As far as I know, Faraday discovered experimentally that a change in magnetic field induces an electric field. However, the units of $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ are both defined by the Lorentz force law $\mathbf F = q(\mathbf E + \mathbf v \times \mathbf B)$, so one can only deduce that $\nabla \times \mathbf E = - \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf B$ for some constant $\alpha$. How did people figure out that this constant is exactly one?

One possible answer is based on the consideration of special relativity, but that would be an anachronism.

I suspect there were experiments confirming that Faraday's law is compatible with Lorentz force law (under some appropriate unit for velocity in terms of the speed of light). Is this the case? If so, when were these experiments carried out, and were they used as evidence supporting special relativity?

Any comment on the relevant history is also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a choice. The SI system of units was defined this way. In [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) units, the proportionality constant is $1/c$, a different choice.

Comment: So you are saying that the unit of $B$ is defined using Faraday's law, either $\nabla \times E = -\frac{d}{dt}B$ or $\nabla \times E = -\frac{1}{c}\frac{d}{dt}B$. But one still needs to verify that Lorentz force law is $F = q(E + v \times B)$, and not $F = q(E + \beta v \times B)$ for some constant $\beta$.

Comment: @TianXia In Gaussian units, your $\beta$ is $1/c$.

Comment: But I don't think that is true by convention. If no units are specified for $E$ and $B$, Faraday's law and Lorentz force law should be $\nabla \times E = -\alpha \frac{d}{dt}B$ and $F = q(\gamma E + \beta v \times B)$. The unit of $E$ is chosen such that $\gamma = 1$, but the unit of $B$ cannot be chosen to simultaneously specify both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. One of these numbers must be determined theoretically or experimentally.

Comment: The experiment is taking a magnet and a coil. Move the coil relative to the magnet, measure the voltage due to Lorentz force. Now move the magnet relative to the coil, measure the EMF due to Faraday's law. And then read On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies (https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~rtaylor/teaching/specrel.pdf) for the theoretical significance.

Comment: I understand that special relativity is a justification of the constants of proportionality. I am just wondering how Faraday's law and Lorentz force law evolved into the form they appear today. Before Einstein's work on relativity, was the unit of $B$ defined using $\nabla \times E = -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}B$ (don't mind the exact constant)? People could have experimentally determined that $F = q(E + \beta v \times B)$ for some constant $\beta$ very close to one, but was there any reason for this constant to be exactly one, before relativity? ...

Comment: If not, then the constant must have been removed after the discovery of special relativity. Furthermore, $\beta = 1$ would be the first experimental evidence that supports special relativity. By the way, thank you for the link to Einstein's paper; it does provide many historical insights.

Comment: I think $\beta=1$ was just common sense to anybody used to Galilean relativity. Electrical machinery depended on it. That Maxwell's equations were incompatible with Galilean relativity doesn't appear to have been understood before Einstein pointed it out.

Comment: You might want to ask a question on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So the fact $\beta = 1$ could be derived from Galilean relativity? This could be the answer to my question. Could you explain or give me a reference for why $\beta = 1$ is a consequence of Galilean relativity. Thank you. I wonder why I cannot upvote the comments

Comment: I already told you. That's the experiment. Move the coil or move the magnet, it makes no difference. Compatible with Galilean relativity. But forget the idea that physics is derived. Experiments are fundamental.

Comment: I am not saying physics can be derived. I am trying to understand why $\beta=1$ is a common sense before special relativity. It is not obvious to me how people came to this conclusion, without special relativity. If it was just an experimental observation, then the factor $\beta$ would have remained in the Lorentz force law until special relativity.

Comment: Why would you expect the moving coil to yield a different result from the moving magnet?

Comment: I see what you mean now. It turns out the answer is much simpler than I thought. Thank you for your patience.